# sql error(1242) : sub query returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables `a_daily` and `o_daily_lcsgeneration`:

i am trying this query :

```
update a_daily
set
  a_daily.Turbine_Generation =  
   (
     select sum(o_daily_lcsgeneration.Turbine_Generation) 
     from o_daily_lcsgeneration 
     where o_daily_lcsgeneration.Location = 1 
     group by o_daily_lcsgeneration.Date
  )
```

but received the above error saying sub query more than 1 row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `GROUP BY` clause

```
UPDATE a_daily
SET a_daily.Turbine_Generation = 
(
        SELECT sum(o_daily_lcsgeneration.Turbine_Generation)
        FROM o_daily_lcsgeneration
        WHERE o_daily_lcsgeneration.Location = 1
)
```

it causes the query to return more than one value of you have multiple dates.

**UPDATE 1**

```
UPDATE  a_daily a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            select g.Date, sum(g.Turbine_Generation) totalSum
            from o_daily_lcsgeneration g
            where g.Location = 1 
            group by g.Date
        ) b ON a.date = b.date
SET     a.Turbine_Generation = b.totalSum
WHERE       a.location = 1
```

or

```
UPDATE  a_daily a
        LEFT JOIN JOIN
        (
            select g.Date, sum(g.Turbine_Generation) totalSum
            from o_daily_lcsgeneration g
            where g.Location = 1 
            group by g.Date
        ) b ON a.date = b.date
SET     a.Turbine_Generation = COALESCE(b.totalSum, 0)
```

Comment: actually i need to sum(o_daily_lcsgeneration.Turbine_Generation) with grouping the date !! is there any alternative solution

Comment: so how do you update the value of `a_daily.Turbine_Generation` if you have multiple values returned in your subquery? can you add the schema of your tables? do you have date on `a_daily` table that you want to match on your subquery?

Comment: @RanjitKumar - do you want to do multiple update on your table with the `SUM` value for every day?  Then you might want to have a different approach.

Comment: every day a set of 45 rows having same date  should be summed and then should be updated in the a_daily table as a sum

Comment: @RanjitKumar added also `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @RanjitKumar - please look at my answer (1st query).  You could substitute the `YYYY-MM-DD` with `TODAY()`, so you could run the update every day without changing the query too much.

Answer (score 1):

Run the subquery and you'll see that it returns more than one row.  You are grouping the results by date, so the `SUM` expression calculates the value for every day.  You could re-write the query as follow:

```
UPDATE a_daily
SET a_daily.Turbine_Generation = (SELECT SUM(o_daily_lcsgeneration.Turbine_Generation) 
                                    FROM o_daily_lcsgeneration 
                                   WHERE o_daily_lcsgeneration.Location = 1 
                                     AND o_daily_lcsgeneration.Date = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                                GROUP BY o_daily_lcsgeneration.Date)
```

or (for a total sum of all events):

```
UPDATE a_daily
SET a_daily.Turbine_Generation = (SELECT SUM(o_daily_lcsgeneration.Turbine_Generation) 
                                    FROM o_daily_lcsgeneration 
                                   WHERE o_daily_lcsgeneration.Location = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update a_daily
set
  a_daily.Turbine_Generation =  (
     select sum(o_daily_lcsgeneration.Turbine_Generation) 
     from o_daily_lcsgeneration where o_daily_lcsgeneration.Location = a_daily.Location  
     group by o_daily_lcsgeneration.Date
  )
```